# What can I do about the overlapping labels in these subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below is a figure I created with matplotlib.  The problem is pretty obvious -- the labels overlap and the whole thing is an unreadable mess.

[image]

I tried calling `tight_layout` for each subplot, but this crashes my ipython-notebook kernel.

What can I do to fix the layout?  Acceptable approaches include fixing the xlabel, ylabel, and title for each subplot, but another (and perhaps better) approach would be to have a single xlabel, ylabel and title for the entire figure.

Here's the loop I used to generate the above subplots:

```
for i, sub in enumerate(datalist):
    subnum = i + start_with
    subplot(3, 4, i)

     # format data (sub is a PANDAS dataframe)
    xdat = sub['x'][(sub['in_trl'] == True) & (sub['x'].notnull()) & (sub['y'].notnull())]
    ydat = sub['y'][(sub['in_trl'] == True) & (sub['x'].notnull()) & (sub['y'].notnull())]

    # plot
    hist2d(xdat, ydat, bins=1000)
    plot(0, 0, 'ro')  # origin

    title('Subject {0} in-Trial Gaze'.format(subnum))
    xlabel('Horizontal Offset (degrees visual angle)')
    ylabel('Vertical Offset (degrees visual angle)')

    xlim([-.005, .005])
    ylim([-.005, .005])
    # tight_layout  # crashes ipython-notebook kernel

show()
```

**Update:**

Okay, so `ImageGrid` seems to be the way to go, but my figure is still looking a bit wonky:

[image]

Here's the code I used:

```
fig = figure(dpi=300)
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(3, 4), axes_pad=0.1)

for gridax, (i, sub) in zip(grid, enumerate(eyelink_data)):
    subnum = i + start_with

     # format data
    xdat = sub['x'][(sub['in_trl'] == True) & (sub['x'].notnull()) & (sub['y'].notnull())]
    ydat = sub['y'][(sub['in_trl'] == True) & (sub['x'].notnull()) & (sub['y'].notnull())]

    # plot
    gridax.hist2d(xdat, ydat, bins=1000)
    plot(0, 0, 'ro')  # origin

    title('Subject {0} in-Trial Gaze'.format(subnum))
    xlabel('Horizontal Offset\n(degrees visual angle)')
    ylabel('Vertical Offset\n(degrees visual angle)')

    xlim([-.005, .005])
    ylim([-.005, .005])

show()
```

Comment: There's a Cookbook example: http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Multiple_Subplots_with_One_Axis_Label (several examples, in fact)

Comment: fyi: `tight_layout` should be called on the figure instance, not the axes. however, `ImageGrid` is the best way to go, IMO

Comment: @PaulH, ack right. Nice catch!  Thanks!  Edit:  that said, you'd think it would raise an explicit exception =/

Comment: @blz Force the bins in the 2D histogram.  Image grid makes the y-axis across rows and the x-axis down columns the same (as in they are the same objects)  Because you are setting the bin number, each of your histograms is slightly different (or something like that).  `ImageGrid` also sets the aspect to be equal.  Also, you should still turn the number of tick labels _way_ down.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist2d see the `bins=[array, array]` kwarg.

Comment: @tcaswell, the `bins=[array, array]` trick works very well, thanks!  How should I go about reducing the number of ticks?  Also, my titles aren't showing up for the subplots.  It's rather important that they do -- any advice?

Comment: change the tick locator.  You should be able to find a question on that already existing, if not start a new one.  Not sure about the sub-plot titles, you might need to make a key (an array of the titles) or something like that.   That is definitely worth another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `ImageGrid` ([tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html)).

First example lifted directly from that link (and lightly modified):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import numpy as np

im = np.arange(100)
im.shape = 10, 10

fig = plt.figure(1, (4., 4.))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, # similar to subplot(111)
                nrows_ncols = (2, 2), # creates 2x2 grid of axes
                axes_pad=0.1, # pad between axes in inch.
                aspect=False, # do not force aspect='equal'
                )

for i in range(4):
    grid[i].imshow(im) # The AxesGrid object work as a list of axes.

plt.show()
```

Comment: awesome!  I'm going to try this in a few minutes!

Comment: I tried using `ImageGrid`, as you suggested, but I'm still getting strange output.  My axes are improperly sized and my xlims and ylims are not taken into account -- I've updated my question with example code and a new figure.  Any thoughts?